# Does Emperor Palpatine have a first name?

Tags: star-wars, names, darth-sidious

Has the first name of Emperor Palpatine been mentioned in any *Star Wars* work?

Comment: I thought that Palpatine *is* this first name.

Comment: Could be Sue.  It would explain why he's so angry all the time.

Comment: @Zoot - Mary Sue?

Comment: I'm just thinking that it would be cool to have Johnny Cash count as part of the extended Star Wars universe.

Comment: It’s Geoff. Geoff Palpatine.

Comment: Palpetine Palpetine...junior.

Comment: @DVK - The Mary Sue is (George) Lucas Skywalker,

Comment: His first name will always be "Emperor" in my mind. He was really just Chancellor Emperor Palpatine and Senator Emperor Palpatine and finally Emperor Emperor Palatine.

Comment: His first name is "Oh-@%$#-Its".

Comment: After The Phantom Menace came out, there was a joke that it was Frank Palpatine, since one of his lines was: "I must be frank, your majesty."

Answer (score 37):

**UPDATE on the origin**

As per [James Luceno's interview](https://apexfan.com/star-wars-with-friends-21-interview-james-luceno/) on "Star Wars With Friends #21" Podcast:

- The name came **directly from George Lucas**
- It was invented a long time ago, for a never-happened years ago live TV series "Underworld"
- In early version of the novel, *Plagueis* discovers it but doesn't use it to stoke Palpatine's ego.
- In *Tarkin*, the fact that someone knows his first name is a sign of being in his inner circle.

**UPDATE from New Disney Canon**:

As per the new canon, the Emperor's first name is **Sheev**
The source is James Luceno's *[Tarkin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tarkin_%28novel%29)* book, released in November 2014.

Here's the blurb from a blog announcing this:

> A few days ago at the "A New Dawn" panel at New York Comic Con, it was revealed that the upcoming novel *Tarkin*, written by James Luceno, will finally reveal Palpatine's first name.

Earlier today the *Star Wars* Wikia Wookieepedia updated their article on Palpatine with the new name and listed page 93 of *Tarkin* as their source. (Obviously one of their editors got an advanced copy of the novel.)

**Quote below**

> **“Thank you, Sheev,” Tarkin said, with obvious sincerity, and using
>   Palpatine’s given name.** “I will do what’s best for my homeworld, and
>   for the Republic — in any manner you deem fit.”

---

**Original answer:**

To complement Phantom's answer, another option aside from Ethril that the fans non-canonically use is "Cos."

The name comes from an early draft of *Episode IV: A New Hope* in which Lucas named the Palpatine-like figure "Cos Dashit."

The name was later sorta-recycled into his father's name, [Cosinga Palpatine](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cosinga_Palpatine).

([src](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118232819/http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarscharacters/a/SWAR_palpatine-first-name.htm))

Comment: Wouldn't the Palpatine-like figure in *A New Hope* have been Darth Vader? Or was this before the story was broken into three movies?

Comment: @Xantec - according to Lucas, the story was **always** broken into 9 movies. </straight_face>

Comment: He carefully outlined every contradiction and plot hole from the start.

Comment: They should have gone with Geoff.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Geoff's a pretty scary name.

Comment: Geoff Vader? One of the funniest youtube videos of all time.

Comment: In its current form this answer is a mess, but it has the info, so +1.

Answer (score 15):

**No first name for the Emperor has been revealed to date.**

Some background to Palpatine's lack of a first name is given in the EU book [*Darth Plagueis*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Plagueis), where it is revealed that he used only his surname to spite his father [Cosinga Palpatine](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cosinga_Palpatine).

[Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_family) sums it up thusly:

> In 82 BBY, Cosinga Palpatine's wife gave birth to their eldest son,
>   Palpatine, who later insisted on being known only by the cognomen in
>   order to spite his father and the rest of the family. The couple also
>   had at least two other sons and two daughters.

Comment: Thats suggests to me his name might be Cosinga (Jr.), then. If I wanted to spite my father by not using my full name, it would be because I have the same literal name.

Answer (score 6):

Officially, it has never been revealed.

Even [StarWars.com](https://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/characters/palpatine/) simply refers to him as "Palpatine".

In 2003, Steve Sansweet [explained](https://web.archive.org/web/20030704091512/http://www.starwars.com/community/askjc/steve/askjc20030701.html)

> Palpatine's first name, if he even has one, has yet to be revealed. That's not so unusual even in our own galaxy. For example, in one of the world's most populous countries, Indonesia, many people go by one name. And even some last names are just that, not family names. In the Star Wars universe, we doubt that there are many in the know for whom just plain "Palpatine" isn't enough.

To date, no EU materials have given him an official first name, though an early draft of [The Visual Dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118232819/http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarscharacters/a/SWAR_palpatine-first-name.htm) supposedly named him "Ethril". I can't find any scan of that online to confirm this though.

Comment: +1, I like the "Frank" theory: 'Finally, some fans have jokingly suggested that Palpatine's first name is Frank, based on the line, "I must be frank, Your Majesty."'

Comment: Surely, you can't be serious.

Comment: Hey, if that name is good enough for the Bunny in Donnie Darko, it's good enough for that fancy emperor.

Comment: That "wooshing" sound you just heard? That was an [*Airplane*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080339/quotes) flying overhead.

Comment: @phantom42 - Don't. Call. Me. Shirley!!!!